# C# Reflection: Instantiate an object with string class name

Tags: c#, reflection

my situation is the next: I'm working with Visual C# 2010 express developing a Windows Forms Application. When the user logins, dinamically build a menustrip with options loaded from a database table. In that table i save id, option name and Form Name.

So, suppose that in my project i have a Form named Contabilidad, it has Contabilidad.cs that is the main class , so if i wanna create a new form and show it i do this:

```
Contabilidad frmConta = new Contabilidad();
frmConta.Show();
```

But in this case, because the menu options are stored in database, in database i only have the string "Contabilidad". So, i want to use C# reflection to create a instance of Contabilidad or any other form only with class name in string format.

First i tried this:

```
Form frmConta= (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Contabilidad").Unwrap();
```

Because i read in a StackOverflow question that if i use null i'm referring to current assembly (my forms are all in the same project), but i get this message:

```
Could not load type 'Contabilidad' from assembly 'AccountingSA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The class definition is the next:

```
namespace AccountingSA {
public partial class Contabilidad : Form
{
    public Contabilidad()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } ...
```

Also i tried this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("AccountingSA");
Type t = assembly.GetType("Contabilidad");
Form frmConta = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

But i get ArgumentNullException with this message:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type
```

Because t variable is null.

What i'm do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the fully-qualified name of the type:

```
Type t = assembly.GetType("AccountingSA.Contabilidad");
```

From the documentation for [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetType_System_String_):

> name Type: System.String
>   The full name of the type.
>   [...] The name parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly.

Answer (score 14):

You're trying to use the name of the class without specifying the namespace. This should be fine:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("AccountingSA");
Type t = assembly.GetType("AccountingSA.Contabilidad");
Form frmConta = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Every version of `GetType` requires the fully-qualified type name; the benefit of using [`Assembly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) is that at least you don't need to also include the *assembly* name, but as documented you still need the namespace:

> The name parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly.

Note that to diagnose something similar in the future, it would have been worth looking at the value of `t` after the second line - it will be null, which is why the third line threw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the namespace:

```
assembly.GetType("AccountingSA.Contabilidad");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Form frmConta= (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "AccountingSA.Contabilidad").Unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your class this way:

```
ContabilidadNamespace.Contabilidad, ContabilidadAssembly
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too late in the thread to answer, but the earlier answer, in current .NET framework (4.7), not working (The line Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("AccountingSA"); always throws FileIOException). Currently, working code is (Use Type directly)

```
Type t = Type.GetType("AccountingSA.Contabilidad");
Form frmConta = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

or other way using Assembly is

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(Form).Assembly;
Type t = assembly.GetType("AccountingSA.Contabilidad");
Form frmConta = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```