# C# Loading a type from a string and declaring a List

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that is designed to accept a List in it's declaration as follows:

```
public class MyHandler
{
    public T LookUp<T>()
    {
        //This method compiles and returns a dynamically typed List
        ...
    }
}
```

I call this method from elsewhere as such:

```
MyHandler mh = new MyHandler();
List<AgeGroup> ageGroups = mh.LookUp<List<AgeGroup>>();
```

This process works great, but I am looking for a way of being able to dynamically load the `AgeGroup` type from a string.

I have found examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052508/c-sharp-reflection-instantiate-an-object-with-string-class-name), but am not able to work out how to implement it in this case. For example, I have tried the following (and does not compile):

```
Type t = Assembly.Load("MyNamespace").GetType("MyNamespace.AgeGroup");
List<t> ageGroups = mh.LookUp<List<t>>();
```

I also tried using `typeof(t)`, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics in C#, using type of a variable as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a generic type at runtime like this:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type typeArg = Assembly.Load("MyNamespace").GetType("MyNamespace.AgeGroup");
listType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeArg);
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Of course you won't be able to use it as a `List<AgeGroup>` unless you know the type parameter at compile time. You also won't be able to use `Lookup<T>` like you did in your example unless you know the type at compile time. You'd have to invoke it like this:

```
MethodInfo lookupMethod = mh.GetType().GetMethod("LookUp");
lookupMethod = lookupMethod.MakeGenericMethod(listType);
lookupMethod.Invoke(mh, null);
```

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thanks :)