# Make a class instance from string and call a constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm making a RTS game. Every Unit in RTS game can do some actions, such as *Patrol*, *Attack* or *Build*. In unity, you can easily manually fill-in `string` and `integer` arrays for C# scripts.

Because of this, I decided that it would be easiest to have a `string[] str_actions` array for ever unit and when unit is first initialised, convert this array to `Action[] actions`.

I can probably [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7052508/607407):

```
string className = "Attack"
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Actions");
Type t = assembly.GetType("Actions."+className);
Action action = (Action)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

But this doesn't handle two problems:

1. Action doesn't have constructor that takes 0 arguments
2. The possibility that `className` refers to class that is not child of `Action`

How do I handle them?

Comment: Don't use reflection; use inheritance. You can use serialization to store the lists off if you choose.

Comment: I'm using inheritance. Every action is child of the `abstract class Action`. But serialisation [*uses* reflection in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436098.aspx) - how else would you get class instances from strings?

Comment: Sure, but its doing all this reflection for you, and you don't need to worry about the two questions (assuming no one is manually modifying the files); or is that what you are worried about?

Comment: Maybe there's a way to do it as you're proposing, but I'm new to C# and I really just want to instantiate classes by their classNames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as posted:

1. Thats ok! Using this overload of Activator.CreateInstance: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) you can pass an object[] in, and it will find the constructor that best fits. Having a default constructor *is* a good idea though, especially if you are going to utilize serialization.
2. You can't "handle" it in the sense that you can avoid it from happening. However, your code as written will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the cast fails. To avoid that, use the `as` operator:

   ```
   Action action = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Action;
   ```

   Now `action` will just hold `null` if the cast is invalid, instead of throwing.

Now for the caveat: `Activator.CreateInstance` is very rarely the right choice in C#. In general, you want to use direct instantiation or deserialization. Granted, deserialization *utilizes* reflection; but all the messy details are abstracted away.

Comment: If no constructor is found, do I get `null` too?

Comment: @TomášZato By the documentation, that would throw a `MissingMethodException`. You would need a try/catch to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured it out. I'm making it a static method `Action.fromString`.  The thing I was lacking was the [`Type.GetConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) method which returns the `ConstructorInfo` object.

```
    public static Action fromString(string className, string defName, WorldObject actor)
    {
        //Get the Assembly (namespace)
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Actions");
        //Get the exact class Type
        Type t = assembly.GetType("Actions." + className);
        //Get the info about constructor (using array literal)
        // - for every accepted parameter enter typeof(parameterType)
        ConstructorInfo constructor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(WorldObject) });
        //Initialise the Type instance
        System.Object action = constructor.Invoke(new System.Object[] { defName, actor });
        //If it's child of the main class
        if (action is Action)
            return (Action)action;
        //Error otherwise
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("'" + className + "' is not child of Action!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```