# Can I get child class instance from `this` in C#?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a RTS game object class `WorldObject`. In RTS games, various actions on objects are dispatched by mouse clicks. I've invented following system:

Every WorldObject has a `Action[]` array that contains available actions. `Action` constructor looks like this:

```
public Action(WorldObject ownerObj) {
    owner = ownerObj;
}
```

In `WorldObject` constructor (actually Unity `Start()` method), `Action`s are instantiated from strings contained in object definition. This is very comfortable, because I can edit actions in Unity UI:

```
        //Load actions
        int l = actions_str.Length;
        actions = new Action[l];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            actions[i] = Action.fromString(actions_str[i], "", this);
            if (actions[i] != null)
                Debug.Log("Created action...");
            else
                Debug.LogWarning("Failed to create action!");
        }
```

The actions are then converted from strings using Reflection:

```
    public static Action.fromString(string className, WorldObject owner) {
          ... some code ...
            //Get the info about constructor (using array literal)
            constructor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(WorldObject) });
          ... some code ...
    }
```

Where owner is some protected variable. Default action is useless, but many classes can inherit from this, like a `BuildUnit:Action`. If you create advanced action, it will only be able to operate on certain units - in this case, `BuildUnit` needs a `Factory:WorldObject` instance, to operate with factories build queue and so on.

This means I have overloaded a constructor in `BuildUnit:Action` to require `Factory`:

```
    public BuildUnit(Factory factory) : base(factory)
    {
        f = factory;
    }
```

But this is what I get as an error when I assign the `BuildUnit` to `Factory`:

```
No suitable constructor found for 'Actions.SpawnEgg'.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Actions.Action:fromString(String, String, WorldObject) (at Assets/WorldObject/Action.cs:66)
Units.WorldObject:Start() (at Assets/WorldObject/WorldObject.cs:349)
Units.Unit:Start() (at Assets/WorldObject/Unit/Unit.cs:38)
```

It appears that the the `WorldObject` instance is passed, rather than the `Factory` sub-instance.

I thought this shouldn't happen. Anyway:

1. In the parent class, if it [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) one of it's children, is still just the parent instance contained in `this`?
2. If so, what should I do to keep the concept working?

Assuming answer is `2.`, I've already figured out an anoying workaround:

```
//The return value should be castable back to original class (as Factory)
protected virtual WorldObject GetThis() {
     return this;
}
```

Comment: The exception is returned  in your `fromString` method, which we can't see the code for. What's the code around line 66 in Action.cs?

Comment: I'm instantiating the [`Action`s from the classNames given as strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26893351/607407) because this is more comfortable. [Here's the full code](http://pastebin.com/6JX6Sj2a). Nevertheless, I think my question is very general one, not dependent on my code.

Comment: Your general question is one thing, and your bug is another. I'll answer in a minute.

Comment: If some part of the code from pastebin is relevant, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different issues here, the general one you're asking about, and the specific error you're having.

**The general question**

There's no such thing as a "parent instance" or "child instance". An instance is always of one specific type, and can always be cast to any other type it matches. This means that if `Factory` inherits `WorldObject`, this will always work:

```
Factory f = new Factory();
WorldObject wo = f;       // Works, because Factory is-a WorldObject.
Factory f2 = (Factory)wo; // Works, because the reference wo points to a Factory object.
```

Your workaround does nothing that my second line won't do = upcasting in an assignment is implicit.

**The specific problem**

The error you're getting is because of how Reflection searchs for types and method signatures. In your code, in line 43, you have this line:

```
constructor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(WorldObject) });
```

What it's doing is searching for a constructor on the action that takes a `WorldObject`. Your action, however, has a constructor that takes a `Factory`, not a `WorldObject`. This makes a difference when using reflection.

It's true that when calling the constructor, the **compiler** knows that a `Factory` is-a `WorldObject` and can match it, but when using reflection, there's a different between a constructor that takes `Factory` and one that takes `WorldObject`. You can have both, and they behave a bit differently, and you have to be explicit about how to call it.

In other words, if you want a generic reflection-based method to instantiate your types, you either need to have them all support the same constructor (in this case, a `WorldObject` ctor), or have your reflection code be smarter (and uglier), iterate over all constructors and look for one whose parameter type is a descendent of `WorldObject`.

Comment: I guess I could get around easily using [`Object.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3), couldn't I?

Comment: your can use `actor.GetType()` to find out the specific WorldObject you're dealing with, and search for a constructor that matches that WO specifically, yes.